# How to change eth0 to wlan0 on kali linux

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux on a virtual machine and I need to enable wlan0 or wireless connection on it. But my vm is on ethernet (eth0) connection. From network connections I had changed NAT to bridged adapter (and also the device name to the available wireless adapter) and restarted the vm, even then the connections on my kali still remain at ethernet connection. How can I change it to wireless? I'm using oracle (not vmware).

Comment: You could take a look into `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` (the actual file name might differ) and see if you can change it within the VM.

Comment: @eblock I checked with the ls command after getting to /etc/udev/rules.d in the terminal but I see nothing. Is it a hidden file?

Comment: This would only change the _name_ -- but changing the name _won't_ magically turn an Ethernet adapter into a Wi-Fi adapter.

Comment: @user1686 that's correct, I didn't read the question carefully enough, I assumed it was about the name. No it's not a hidden file, but as already commented it won't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you can change the name of a network interface, but this will not transform an Ethernet connection into a Wi-Fi connection or vice versa.

What you need to do is to add a new wireless interface `wlan0` on your VM; this is done on the VM settings, on Oracle VM Virtualbox or VMware Workstation or whatever your virtualization solution is.

Then you must enable it via

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

run as root.

Comment: Is it possible on a physical machine and not just a VM?

Comment: On a physical machine you need to have the necessary hardware, of course (wireless NIC or Ethernet NIC).